# Nested Forms not working from Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, nested

HEllo and really thx for this great website ok here is the idea i got a database like this:

```
CategoryID CategoryName ParentID
---------------------------------
1          FirstMenuCat1          NULL
2          FirstMenuCat2          NULL
3          SubMenuCat1            1
4          SubMenuCat2            1
5          SubMenuCat3            2
```

and i want it to show 2 menus the idea is to choose option from menu 1 and then enable second menu to choose the options from but i want menu 2 to show the options that have same parentID

```
function get_tables(){
require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');

$queryCats ="SELECT *
                    FROM menus
                    WHERE ParentID = NULL
                    ORDER BY CategoryID;";
 $querySubCats ="SELECT *
                    FROM menus
                    WHERE ParentID = $selected
                    ORDER BY CategoryID;";

 }
 echo  $queryCats;
 echo '<select name="cat">';
 foreach ($queryCats as $key =>$value){
     echo "<option value=\"$key\">
     $value</option>\n";
 }
 echo '</select>';
 $selected = '</select>';

 echo '<select name="subcat">';
 foreach ($querySubCats as $key =>$value){
     echo "<option value=\"$key\">
     $value</option>\n";
 }
 echo '</select>';



 echo '<h1>Select a Category:</h1>
 <form method="post">';

 get_tables();
 echo '</form>';
 ?>
```

Ok now im trying to make this appear but i still need help any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break this into two parts:

1. get and display the values for the base menu
2. when a value is selected load the appropriate secondary menu

There are lots of samples out there for v similar pages. Read on `ajax` and `dynamic menus` and you'll probably find what you want.

If you want to do the whole thing via PHP it's a v similar process. Change your function header to include a $selection param. Select for menus with that `ParentID`. Start the process by calling this page / function with $selection = NULL.

**EDIT:**

```
change: 
  function get_tables(){  
    -to-  
  function get_tables( $selection ){
```

Comment: 'Change your function header to include a $selection param.'  How i do that? and really thx for quick answer!!